# How to prepare definition file for npm?

Tags: typescript, npm

I'd like to bundle definition file (.d.ts) to a npm module following [this manual](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typings-for-npm-packages.html). How should I reference [node](https://github.com/typed-typings/env-node/blob/master/4/node.d.ts) itself as it is forbidden to use `\\\ <reference />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reference the Node typings at all, the user of your module will need to install them separately.

Comment: I see. I was hoping for some explicit information - the user of my module needs to know that the module uses something else. In this case my module is Node only (does not support browser), therefore Node reference is obvious. Still I need to `import` used Node modules which seems to work.

Does this approach apply also for 3rd party modules (or just Node itself)?

Comment: @ahz If you use [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings/) to manage the type definitions of dependencies then it will automate installation of the relevant type definitions for non-global dependencies. Unfortunately, many type definitions are currently only available from DefinitelyTyped (and are assumed to be global) and as such will have to be installed manually by the user of your module. I don't remember if `typings` will notify the user of your module about global type definitions they may be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
/// <reference types="node" />
```